# informix replace null value with 0 in select

Tags: c#, informix

I  want replace null value with 0 and if not null i want to count the data ??

```
sql = "SELECT b.start,COUNT(a.resourceid)  " +
      "FROM t1 b,agentconnectiondetail a "+
      "WHERE TO_CHAR(a.startdatetime,'%R') >= TO_CHAR(b.start,'%R') AND TO_CHAR(a.enddatetime,'%R') <= TO_CHAR(b.finish,'%R') " +
      "AND a.resourceid = '"+dr[1].ToString()+"'" +
      "GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 1";
```

that query output is null

what must I do ??

Comment: luigi your answer result is

ERROR [42000] [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix]A syntax error has occurred.

Comment: Use the NVL : `COUNT(NVL(a.resourceid,0))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At first you should create simple query with simple db table, some values and requested result that clearly shows your problem.

Part 1: *I want replace null value with 0*

To change NULL into some value you can use `NVL()` function. Documentation says: *The NVL expression returns different results, depending on whether its first argument evaluates to NULL.*

Examples:

```
SELECT fld, NVL(fld, 0) FROM ...
```

Part 2: *and if not null i want to count the data*

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ... WHERE fld IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Are Start and finish both datetime datatypes ? If they are DATE then %R (HH:MM) is probably meaningless.

If they are Datetime then why not

```
SELECT b.start,COUNT(a.resourceid)  " +
  "FROM t1 b,agentconnectiondetail a "+
  "WHERE startdatetime  >= b.start AND a.enddatetime <= b.finish" +
  "AND a.resourceid = '"+dr[1].ToString()+"'" +
  "GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 1";
```

If start and finish are dates then you can always extend() to be the same startdatetime and enddatetime